# Anyone knows How to Auto Select an option from <Li> Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

Here is the element I got from a ebsite

I want to make a script that I can use to auto select a size (Like 12).

```
<div class="select-size select-size-detail" id="sizeOptions" style="display: block;">
<div></div>
<ul class="select-box-size">                                                        
<li currupc="00886737650974">6.5</li>
<li currupc="00886737650981">7</li>
<li currupc="00886737659267">7.5</li>
<li currupc="00886737659274">8</li>
<li currupc="00886737659281">8.5</li>
<li currupc="00886737659304">9</li>
<li currupc="00886737659328">9.5</li>
<li currupc="00886737659335">10</li>
<li currupc="00886737659342">10.5</li>
<li currupc="00886737659359">11</li>
<li currupc="00886737659397">12</li>                                                        
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming it is working like an `option` element… If you want your `li` to be selected on page load, you could put the `selected` property in your html like this: `<li currupc="00886737659397" selected>12</li>`

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm going to assume this is using some third party source to make the **List** **i**tems appear as `options` in a drop-down selection. Maybe if you use inspect element while changing the selection you might find a `class` name or some other attribute is being added upon selection which would indicate exactly how to pre-select something from that element.

Comment: @TakitIsy So I just need to type <li currupc="00886737659397" selected>12</li> in the console section on that website it will select automatically?? thanks

Comment: @NewToJS https://www.nike.com.hk/product/942842-103/detail.htm?pdpRecommend=false&preSkuCode= Here is the Link I don't know which one should I looking for, I just want to make a script that i can auto select the size and add to cart haha . thanks bro

Comment: @NewToJS when I selected a certain size this pop out <p class="pdp-size">尺碼(US&nbsp;12)</p>

Comment: @TakitIsy an `<li>` doesn't work the same as an `<option>`. Adding `selected` will do nothing. Adding  `class="selected"` makes more sense

Comment: @charlietfl hey do you have any cue of handling this thanks

Comment: @AnfieldWong Yes, I am currently pre-selecting size 12 using the browser console and using inspect element to check the correct element and class is being assigned. If you open your browser console and inspect the `li` elements as you change them you will see exactly which changes are required for you to pre-select the options you want. This requires very little work but I will not share/example my method until I see you have actually tried something of your own. This isn't a free writing service.

Comment: @NewToJS Yeah that's right I just find out that <p class="pdp-size">尺碼(US&nbsp;12)</p> by changing the number like I type 13 instead of 12 it changes the size into 13

Comment: <li currupc="00886737659397" class="select-size-selected">12</li>

Comment: @NewToJS Got it !! see whats going on now !!

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks !!

Comment: @NewToJS but I don't know what to do next cause i know nothing about Javascript I just start learning from today

Comment: @AnfieldWong Target the `li` you want and trigger a `click()` event. Any click events attached to the element will trigger making the selection. This isn't a standard drop list so by adding a `class` name it will mean removing the old one and might also require some other changes for it to work properly so the quickest way around this would be to use the `click` function.

Comment: @NewToJS   var button = document.getElementsByTagName("<li currupc="00886737659397">12</li>");
button1.click()

Comment: @NewToJS I tried this but it said Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @AnfieldWong that isn't how you use that selector. Maybe try something like this `document.getElementById('sizeOptions').getElementsByTagName('li')[10].click();`

Comment: @NewToJS ('li')[10] what [10] means here ?? I don't get it thanks

Comment: @AnfieldWong`getElementsByTagName()` returns a node list/Collection of elements. `[10]`  is selecting a specific node (element) from that list.

Comment: @NewToJS Got it THanks !! i got another problem again I want to have a auto add to cart function I have located the path but after I modify your code it not working on this case

Comment: @NewToJS                                                                                              <a class="btn-black block fLeft addToCart display_block">加入購物車</a>

Comment: @NewToJS document.getElementByClassName("btn-black block fLeft addToCart display_block").click() That's not working                                       It said Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('li').click(function(){
 $('li').each(function(){ $(this).css({'border-style':'none'}); });
 $(this).css({'border-style':'solid','border-width':'2px','border-color':'gray'});
 alert('Select '+$(this).text() );
});

function click_li_by_value(_value){
 $('li').each(function(){
    var li_text=$(this).text();
    if(li_text==_value){
      $(this).click();
    }
 });
}


click_li_by_value('12');  //or '11'  or  '10.5'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="select-size select-size-detail" id="sizeOptions" style="display: block;">
  <div>
   <ul class="select-box-size">
     <li currupc="00886737650974">6.5</li>
     <li currupc="00886737650981">7</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659267">7.5</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659274">8</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659281">8.5</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659304">9</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659328">9.5</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659335">10</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659342">10.5</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659359">11</li>
     <li currupc="00886737659397">12</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Man Do you know how to bypass Captcha by using Javascript

Comment: I do not use Captcha any check can be arranged by checking $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'], SESSION, cookies... etc...

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean :( I am new to this game I will want to bypass the Captcha or Autofill it Find lot of material none can help :( thanksssss

Comment: I've never tried to bypass Captcha or any other service. I've never had such a task...

Comment: haha if you are free you should try it!! quite challenging which you may have fun on it bro hahaaaa

Comment: hey bro I tried your method but it said $ is not a function anyway to fix this ? thanks